# Displaying XML feed content

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, file-get-contents

I am trying to get the contents from an xml feed and display them in a list. My test below is just to get the job_title for a vacancy.

```
$feed = file_get_contents('https://www.jobs.nhs.uk/search_xml?client_id=120650');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);

$items = $xml->nhs_search->vacancy_details;

foreach($items as $item) {
    $job_title = $item->job_title;
    echo $job_title;
}
```

Here is a snippet of the xml feed

```
<nhs_search>
    <vacancy_details>
        <id>915854585</id>
        <job_title>Band 5 Speech and Language Therapist</job_title>
    </vacancy_details>
</nhs_search>
```

Nothing is displaying and no errors.

Comment: Hi, when you say this "isn't working", can you clarify a bit? Do you get any errors or warnings in your logs? Does some content output but not what you expect? It would also be useful to have a [mcve] - rather than the link to the XML, can you include a small sample of the XML you're trying to process in the question itself?

Comment: I have updated the question to include a snippet from the xml feed. There are no errors and nothing is being returned. (Someone has provided answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work fine:

```
$feed = file_get_contents('https://www.jobs.nhs.uk/search_xml?client_id=120650');

$xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);

$items = $xml->vacancy_details;

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $id = $item->id;
    $job_title = $item->job_title;
    echo $id; echo '<br />';
    echo $job_title;
}
```

Changed `$items = $xml->nhs_search->vacancy_details;` to `$items = $xml->vacancy_details;`

Comment: "I edited your code" — In what way? What did you do to solve the problem? Answers shouldn't be games of spot-the-difference.

Comment: It's working now thanks. I have added what the change was - but not sure why it works.

Comment: @JohnFotios check please documentation - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php